# C++ - QtCreator doesn't show any output

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "hello";

    return a.exec();
}
```

This basic application doesn't work when building and running in QtCreator 2.6.2. I'm using Qt 5.0.1.

Not even my program runs; the only thing that runs is `qcreator_process_stub.exe`. In my `.pro` file, the line `CONFIG += console` is there, and in my `.pro.user` file, `UseTerminal` is set to true.

But my question is why my program doesn't show and what is `qcreator_process_stub.exe`?

Edit: Standard output doesn't even show.

Comment: What QtCreator (IDE) version are you using? The version you wrote was the Qt version. You see it in *Help -> About Qt Creator*.

Comment: @leemes QtCreator 2.6.2

Comment: If you want to run a console application *inside* QtCreator, I mean, show the output in the 'Application Output' tab, *deselect* the run in terminal option in the project settings. The run in terminal option will launch a different process, which then opens your program. It seems like this step could not be done in your case, whatever the reason might be... (My experience with this option is not much better on Linux...)

Comment: @leemes It seems to work for this guy here, so I'm not sure why I can't do it in the IDE http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Id-sPu_m_hE&list=SP2D1942A4688E9D63&index=2

Comment: He uses a 2 years old QtCreator version. A lot has changed since then. I don't know how it works in Windows. I only know this workaround.

Comment: @leemes It would seem silly that QtCreator have a `Run` function to make it do nothing.

Comment: I didn't say that. I said I don't know how it works in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

QtCreator was detecting the wrong MinGW version on my system (as I used another version for Code::Blocks). What I did was:

**Tools > Options... > Build & Run > Kits**

I then cloned the Auto-detected kit, and changed the compiler to the one that shipped with QtCreator. Every time I create a project, I have to build it with that kit.

Answer (score 2):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdebug.html#details

`qcreator_process_stub.exe` is the default terminal that Qt Console programs get executed in.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#qDebug

> This function does nothing if QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT was defined during compilation.

Try putting this at the top of your main:

```
#ifdef QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
#undef QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
#endif
```